# Angular 2 event when current route guard is executed

Tags: angular

I have a root component `AppComponent`.

Template of AppComponent:

```
some content
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
some content
```

The `<router-outlet>` will contain content of current route. There are many routes in application. Some of them has asynchronous guards. I want to execute some code when guard will be executed.

Something like that:

```
export class AppComponent {
    ngOnChildComponentIsReady() {
        // ... some code
    }
}
```

Is it possible?

The point is to show progress bar when page is opened at first time. Progress bar will be hidden when route component will be ready to render. It will be ready to render when route guards will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The most common scenario is to write method iniside `ngOnInIt ()` of the component to which you are redirected from the route. Also you can make use of `EventEmiiter` to catch that event.